# Use of CoreGraphics Loop Draw Creating Performance Issues

Tags: performance, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect

I am interested in overriding drawRect in a subclassed UIView to create a simple textured background for a tableView. I have accomplished my goal, but the performance is not so great. I understand this is something of a common issue with newbies like myself. However,  as this is my first go at CoreGraphics, I am having trouble diagnosing the source of the issue.

By performance hit, I mean there is a lag before the tableViewController is animated in via a navigation controller. It hangs, if you will. The performance hit occurs the first time any of my UITableViewControllers are inited, with the appropriate setting of [[self tableView] setBackgroundView:level1View];. Subsequent rendering of the table views has 0 performance hit. Performance issues go away when I don't set the backgroundView property to my custom drawn view. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Couple caveats: I would rather not tile an image for this, unless it is the only performant way to do so. (Trying to learn and what not.) Also, I based my code on the tutorial found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2167/core-graphics-101-patterns

```
#import "HordLevel1View.h"

static inline double radians (double degrees) { return degrees * M_PI/180; }
void MyDrawColoredPattern1 (void *info, CGContextRef context)
{

UIColor * dotColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0.90 alpha:1.0];
UIColor * shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, dotColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), .25, shadowColor.CGColor);

//First line of circles
CGContextAddArc(context, 1, 1, 1, 0, radians(360), 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddArc(context, 3, 2, 1, 0, radians(360), 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddArc(context, 5, 0, 1, 0, radians(360), 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddArc(context, 5, 3, 1, 0, radians(360), 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddArc(context, 1, 4, 1, 0, radians(360), 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddArc(context, 3, 5, 1, 0, radians(360), 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextAddArc(context, 5, 6, 1, 0, radians(360), 0);
CGContextFillPath(context);

}


@implementation HordLevel1View

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIColor * bgColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0.85 alpha:1.0];
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, bgColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

static const CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = { 0, &MyDrawColoredPattern1, NULL };

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGColorSpaceRef patternSpace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, patternSpace);
CGColorSpaceRelease(patternSpace);

CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate(NULL,
                                       rect,
                                       CGAffineTransformIdentity,
                                       6,
                                       6,
                                       kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
                                       true,
                                       &callbacks);
CGFloat alpha = 1.0;
CGContextSetFillPattern(context, pattern, &alpha);
CGPatternRelease(pattern);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry nobody got to this, hope my reply is still relevant!  i'm sure you've come a long way since March.

my first thought is that an image is not just a fast way to go, it's simpler code and more flexible too.  but let's say you need to draw dynamically, because the content fundamentally changes in response to user input ( i think this is not likely :] ).

in that case, a few more thoughts:

- create the pattern ONCE, not once every drawRect call, and not once per cell view.
- better yet, use your pattern to create a UIImage, and use that in your cells
- use the correct bounds for the pattern (i think you are making a pattern the size of the entire view)